I'm missing the jarutils.jar on android studio installed as snap on debian
it seems I'm missing a core jar for android studio. Here is the error message:
> 2024-12-17 18:36:17,974 [  21943] SEVERE -
> #c.i.c.s.i.BuildProcessClasspathManager - Cannot add 'jarutils.jar' from 'Android 241.15989.150.2411.11948838' (plugin path:
> /snap/android-studio/161/plugins/android) to compiler classpath
> [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]
> com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot add 'jarutils.jar'
> from 'Android 241.15989.150.2411.11948838' (plugin path:
> /snap/android-studio/161/plugins/android) to compiler classpath
> [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]   at
> com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManagerKt.findClassesRoot(BuildProcessClasspathManager.kt:154)
>   at
> com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManagerKt.computeCompileServerPluginsClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.kt:171)
>   at
> com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManagerKt.access$computeCompileServerPluginsClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.kt:1)
>   at
> com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.getStaticClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.kt:85)
>   at
> com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.getBuildProcessPluginsClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.kt:76)
>   at
> com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.getBuildProcessClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.kt:45)
>   at
> com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.launchBuildProcess(BuildManager.java:1583)
>   at
> com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.lambda$scheduleBuild$16(BuildManager.java:994)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.BackgroundTaskUtil.lambda$submitTask$8(BackgroundTaskUtil.java:266)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.BackgroundTaskUtil.lambda$createBackgroundTask$10(BackgroundTaskUtil.java:302)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$0(ProgressManager.java:100)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:217)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:660)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:735)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:691)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:659)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:79)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:202)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.runProcess(ProgressManager.java:100)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.BackgroundTaskUtil.lambda$createBackgroundTask$11(BackgroundTaskUtil.java:297)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:244)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:30)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.executeFirstTaskAndHelpQueue(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:222)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:218)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:210)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
>   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Here is my development platform :
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:12
Codename:bookworm

I used snap to install android studio on debian
$ snap info android-studio
name:      android-studio
summary:   The IDE for Android
publisher: Snapcrafters✪
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/android-studio
contact:   https://github.com/snapcrafters/android-studio/issues
license:   unset
description: |
  Android Studio provides the fastest tools for building apps on every type
  of Android device.
  
  World-class code editing, debugging, performance tooling, a flexible build
  system, and an instant build/deploy system all allow you to focus on
  building unique and high quality apps.
  
  
  This snap is maintained by the Snapcrafters community, and is not necessarily endorsed or
  officially maintained by the upstream developers.
commands:
  - android-studio
snap-id:      VNTeIi51l6cIZ1gaWHwx0PoP7JaCb61c
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: today at 18:35 CET
channels:
  latest/stable:    2024.1.1.11-Koala   2024-07-14 (161) 1GB classic
  latest/candidate: 2024.2.1.12-Ladybug 2024-12-03 (177) 1GB classic
  latest/beta:      ↑                                        
  latest/edge:      2024.2.1.12-Ladybug 2024-12-04 (178) 1GB classic
installed:          2024.1.1.11-Koala              (161) 1GB classic

I checked with locate to know where is the jarutils.jar file on my system and it looks like it is entirely missing from my system.
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate jarutils.jar
$

Where can I find this file and add it to the snap I'm using ?

Have you tried directly installing Android Studio without snap?

No, I didn't try to install android studio without snap and I'd rather not do it.
